# Replacing rows from one data frame with rows from another data frame

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames, one of which contains a missing value. The first data frame is as follows:

```
data <- data.frame(Name = c("Dex","Dex","Rex","Rex","Rex","Lex","Lex","Nex","Nex","Nex"),
                   Year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, NA, 2001, 2002))

# Name  Year
# DEX   2000
# DEX   2001
# REX   2000
# REX   2002
# REX   2002
# LEX   2001
# LEX   2002
# NEX    NA
# NEX   2001
# NEX   2002
```

The second data frame:

```
data1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Nex","Nex","Nex"), Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002))

# Name  Year
# NEX   2000
# NEX   2001
# NEX   2002
```

I would like to replace the missing value in the data frame `data` with the appropriately placed value from data frame `data1`.

The result should be:

```
# Name  Year
# DEX   2000
# DEX   2001
# REX   2000
# REX   2002
# REX   2002
# LEX   2001
# LEX   2002
# NEX   2000
# NEX   2001
# NEX   2002
```

It seems that it would be easiest to either replace the 3 rows called NEX in `data` with the 3 rows in `data1` or to somehow merge the 2 data frames such that the rows in `data1` are merged with the appropriate rows of `data`. However, I'm at a loss for how to do this.

Comment: I can't see a systemic way to solve that. The column name apparently four factors (DEX, REX, LEX, NEX), however there are multiple values that the factors can assume. What would happen if you have NA values for two different year's in the same factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming order is meaningful here (by groups in data and stand-alone in data1), you can add an an id column to join.

```
data <- data.frame( Name = c("Dex","Dex","Rex","Rex","Rex","Lex","Lex",
                             "Nex","Nex","Nex"), Year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, NA, 2001, 2002 ))

data1 <- data.frame( Name = c("Nex","Nex","Nex"), Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002))

data <- data %>%
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate( # creating index by groups to join
    Index = 1:n()
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

data1 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate( # index, no groups
    Index = 1:n()
  )

dataFill <- data %>% 
  left_join(data1, by = c("Name", "Index")) %>% 
  mutate( # if_else will help us fill in values that are missing selectively
    YearComplete = if_else(
      is.na(Year.x),
      Year.y,
      Year.x
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a combination of `left_join` and `anti_join` (from `dplyr`).

First, I'm loading data with `character` instead of `factor`, since fixing things can tend to conflict on row-binding.

```r
data <- data.frame(Name = c("Dex","Dex","Rex","Rex","Rex","Lex","Lex", "Nex","Nex","Nex"),
                   Year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, NA, 2001, 2002 ),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Nex","Nex","Nex"), Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now the fancy stuff:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  filter(is.na(Year)) %>%
  select(-Year) %>%
  left_join(data1, by = "Name") %>%
  anti_join(data, by = c("Name", "Year")) %>%
  bind_rows(filter(data, !is.na(Year)))
#    Name Year
# 1   Nex 2000
# 2   Dex 2000
# 3   Dex 2001
# 4   Rex 2000
# 5   Rex 2001
# 6   Rex 2002
# 7   Lex 2001
# 8   Lex 2002
# 9   Nex 2001
# 10  Nex 2002
```

The order is a little off because I haven't re-sorted anything, but you can easily fix that with `arrange`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an easy way to do this.  Firstly filter out the instances of "Nex" in `Name`, given we probably don't know the full relevance of order then stack one dataframe on top of the other with `bind_rows`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  filter(Name != "Nex") %>%
  bind_rows(data1)

   Name Year
1   Dex 2000
2   Dex 2001
3   Rex 2000
4   Rex 2001
5   Rex 2002
6   Lex 2001
7   Lex 2002
8   Nex 2000
9   Nex 2001
10  Nex 2002
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
Assumed:
(1) you always have a data table of NEX without NA.
(2) And the order is always the same as the data table with NA

```
data$Year[data$Name == "Nex" ] <- data1$Year
```